# Calculus series homework with variable a

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I have a series:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\sin\frac{a}{n}$$
I'm supposed to check how it behaves with different $a$ values. First I would check if it converges absolutely:
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left| (-1)^n\sin\frac{a}{n}\right| \sim \lim_{n\to \infty} \left| (-1)^n\frac{a}{n}\right|=\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{a}{n}$$
That limit equals $0$ if $a\in \mathbb{R}$, which means that this series always diverges absolutely.

How does it behave not absolutely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The series is clearly convergent for $a=0$.

Now let $a\ne0$ so we have by the Taylor series
$$(-1)^n\sin\left(\frac{a}{n}\right)=\underbrace{(-1)^n\frac{a}{n}}_{=u_n}+\underbrace{O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)}_{=v_n}$$

The series $\sum_n u_n$ is convergent by the Leibniz theorem and the series $\sum_n v_n$ is convergent by comparison with the Riemann series. Hence the given series is convergent for all $a$.

The series isn't absolutely convergent for $a\ne0$ since 
$$\left|(-1)^n\sin\left(\frac{a}{n}\right)\right|\sim_\infty \frac{|a|}{n}.$$

Answer (score 0):

For large $n, \sin \frac an \approx \frac an$ so the series converges like $\ln 2$